# How to get linux version set in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I want to build a shell script. There should be a conditional flag for CentOS version. I want to set a variable for that version like this

```
VERSION := $(lsb_release -sr)
```

But when I included this part I got error. Please someone help me to get the version in shell script.

N.B : `lsb_release sr` works fine when I give this command in terminal.

Comment: It's `uname -r`. Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: because I am compiling a C++ code in shell script.

Comment: I only need the version like 5.6, 6.3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell script:

`VERSION=$(lsb_release -sr)` or `VERSION=$(/usr/bin/lsb_release -sr)` with full path.

will store the release value in $VERSION. What error are you getting ??

Comment: Did you try as said above ??

Comment: yup. I have written both suggestions.

Comment: Did bash say incorrect  ?? what is the output : `echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

`uname -r`

```
-r, --kernel-release     print the kernel release
```

In my case it is showing only `2.6.39`

Or try yourself as `uname --help` for appropriate choice for you.

Comment: ok thanks... will you write a line, what you should have been done for writing in shell script? my problem is there. I think I am doing wrong in shell script.

Comment: i think you are doing right..i am not so good in shell script..just check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856525/better-way-to-check-linux-version)  or [try this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23050/how-to-write-a-script-that-effectively-determines-distro-name)